# Jmeter: How to run 2 or more different HTTP requests at the same time in a thread group?

Tags: http, jmeter

I have below Jmeter Test Plan:

```
Test Plan
    Thread Group(thread number=10,Ramp-up Period=0, loop count=1)
        HTTP request 1
        HTTP request 2
```

My question is how to make above sorts of above 2 HTTP request to send at the same time in this thread group?

My meaning is like scenarios:

```
 start time      http quest
 13:00:00.000    1~10 HTTP request 1
 13:00:00.000    1~10 HTTP request 2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want these requests to start at same time then they should be in different thread groups.

Comment: Could you give me a explicit example? Thank you!

Comment: Just create a new thread group with same config and move request 2 in it